# Google Services is killing my battery by keeping phone awake

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, battery-life, google-apps

In the last few days my Galaxy S3 has gone from lasting 12-13 hours to about 6 hours. On checking the battery monitor it seems to suggest that the phone is constantly staying awake and that Google Services are to blame.

I was recently experiencing real problems with Google Chrome freezing the phone so I have uninstalled and gone back to the native browser but the battery issue persists...

[image: Battery Image 1]
[image: Battery Image 2]
[image: Battery Image 3]

Has anyone experienced anything similar....is a factory reset the only solution? (Android version 4.1.1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After trawling through all manner of options I isolated the root cause of this issue.

Within Google Account Sync I had a look at all available settings and the one that seemed to be causing an issue was 'Sync Internet' option which was just constantly running (and appearing to be keeping the phone awake.

Switching this off has got back my battery back to normal.

I still have no idea why my phone was trying to sync the ***entire*** internet :-)

Comment: Maven, perhaps?

Comment: sync internet probably means your computer browser history and data is synced with your mobile chrome browser. that is the worst data consumption part.

Comment: @thavan There is a separate setting for synchronizing Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Dean's answer, I also had a number of Android apps that drained my battery by using Sync all day long. The apps listed in your Accounts tab under Settings all sync through Google Services. By using Tasker, I scheduled Sync to run every hour for 3 minutes. My battery life improved significantly after that. Here is the recipe for the Tasker profile:

Sync Scheduler Profile

- Time: From 06:00 Till 23:00 (repeat every 1h)

Task

- Action 1 (optional): Notify [ Title: Sync Scheduler, Text: Now Syncing!, Icon: your choice ]
- Action 2: Auto-Sync [ Set:On ]
- Action 3: Wait [ MS:0, Seconds:0, Minutes:3, Hours:0, Days:0 ]
- Action 4: Auto-Sync [ Set:Off ]

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to thank Dean for his answer. "Google services" was draining my battery like crazy as well, and after turning off a bunch of Google account sync options - including "Sync internet" - my S3's battery life has noticeably improved. I now only sync email, calendar, and contacts. (I also outright disabled the Google Search app, though, which includes Google Now, so that could be playing a part as well.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this answer here, so adding this as the problem described is similar to a problem that I had just this week.

Battery drain started happening for my huawei p9 a few days ago all of a sudden, no apparent cause. Google Play Services top battery user but also a variety of other apps.

A suggestion to **turn off automatic app updates** solved the problem for me (after I had done general cleanup and os upgrade and removed a google account(for which authentication was out of date) which had not solved problem).