# Google Services battery usage

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, battery, battery-life, 4.2-jelly-bean

I recently updated to the 10.1 M snapshot of CyanogenMod for my Sprint Galaxy S3 (d2spr). Ever since I did the update, I have been seeing crazy high battery usage from Google Services. I have tried just about everything I can think of to shut it off, but nothing seems to be working. I'm connected to Wi-Fi most of the day, so I don't think 3G has anything to do with it.

### Attempted Troubleshooting:

1. Turn off Google Account Sync (per [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34816/google-services-is-killing-my-battery-by-keeping-phone-awake))
2. Turn off Google Now
3. Turn off Location reporting

If possible, I'd like to fix this without using Juice Defender or any other battery management apps, but if that's what it takes, so be it.

So how can I get Google Services to stop sucking the life out of my phone?

[image: Google Services - 37%]
[image: Google Services detail - keep awake 2 hours]

Comment: Please take a look at [Google Services is killing my battery by keeping phone awake](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34816/16575). Comparing the descriptions, ut looks exactly like your problem (updated my answer below accordingly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely some app utilizing Google Services. You don't show the details screen to be reached when tapping the graph on top of your first screenshot. Please check there, and cross-check with [How to deal with (orphaned) WakeLocks?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34969/16575) -- the "keep awake" of your second screenshot suggest Wakelocks as the "source of evil". The part *What if it is the Android System itself?* should help you track the issue down further.

Another possible -- no, very likely candidate is found in another question I just stumbled upon: [Google Services is killing my battery by keeping phone awake](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34816/16575). Sound familiar? ;)

Comment: Following up, I used BetterBatteryStats to uncover that it was, in fact, location services sucking the life out of my battery. I turned off location services via Settings -> Location Access. This has the unfortunate consequence of disabling Google Now. But for now, at least, it looks like it is one or the other.

Comment: Oh -- that turns Google Now off? Good to now -- thanks for mentioning that feature :) Btw: If you follow the first mentioned link, you'll find another link to an article explaining how to find out who's really behind it (which app is *causing* location services to suck your battery). So you can kill that app, turn location access back on, and enjoy Google Now. Unfortunately, this will require root AFAIR... ([Pinpointing Android LocationManagerService battery drain](http://www.setera.org/2012/09/10/pinpointing-android-locationmanagerservice-battery-drain/))